# Display an image when mouseover event is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Canvas.js to create a doughnut-type chart.
Basically, I'd like to display an image in the middle of the doughnut when the mouse hovers a part of the graph (each country would have its own image).

The mouseover event exists in the library, but I can't seem to trigger anything else than an alert.

Thank you so much.

Link to the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/83gxL/

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
{

  data: [
  {        
            type: "doughnut",
            startAngle: 60,                          


            showInLegend: true,
            dataPoints: [
            {  y: 80500000, label: "Germany", legendText: "Germany" },
            {  y: 66000000, label: "France", legendText: "France" },
            {  y: 63200000, label: "UK", legendText: "UK" },
            {  y: 38500000, label: "Poland", legendText: "Poland" },
            {  y: 59700000, label: "Italy", legendText: "Italy" },
            {  y: 46700000, label: "Spain", legendText: "Spain" },
            {  y: 20100000, label: "Romania", legendText: "Romania" },
            {  y: 7400000, label: "Bulgaria", legendText: "Bulgaria" },
            {  y: 10800000, label: "Greece", legendText: "Greece" },
            {  y: 10500000, label: "Portugal", legendText: "Portugal" },            

            ]
        }
        ]
    });
```

## Second part

The second problem is that I need a different image for every part of the doughnut chart.

Is there a way to ask the library to differentiate between the different sections (i.e. between France, Italy, Germany...)?

Thanks again!

Comment: did try this i think you missed something http://jsfiddle.net/83gxL/1/

Comment: @CognitiveDesire Hum, it makes everything disappear...

Comment: it means that mouse over works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `mouseover` and use it to return a value of your dataset, in this example I have used **name** but you could change that to **legend**. With this value you can update the background image as shown below.

```
  data: [
  {
    mouseover: function(e){            
        document.getElementById('chartContainer').style.backgroundImage = "url('" + e.dataPoint.name + ".png')";
    },
```

You will also need to edit the CSS to position the image, the following should help.

```
#chartContainer
{
    background-position:center;
}
.canvasjs-chart-canvas
{
    background-color:transparent !important;
}
```

I have updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83gxL/2/).

You will need to use the developer tools to see the background change as I have not linked it to any images.

Comment: It seems to be a pretty nice solution!
However, it returns me this error: "Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped."

Comment: All right, with `style.backgroundImage = "url('base.jpeg')";` it works fine. 

Just need the background not to repeat : 
Add in the CSS `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Comment: I just modified @Jonathan's JSFiddle a bit. Checkout http://jsfiddle.net/83gxL/3/

Comment: Here is a slightly updated version http://jsfiddle.net/83gxL/4/

In the previous JSFiddle because the event handler was attached to dataSeries's mouseover event, image was not changing when mouse is moved from one dataPoint to another directly - it required us to move out of dataSeries each time and hover again.

In the current one I've attached event handler to individual dataPoints.